# Auto Logout of App when in Background

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I Have created an app  which will  log out within 1 Min; when it is running in the background, by employing Alarm Mgr method. However, when I debug and run in on Android based device, nothing happens. I have run some basic diagnostic test and found out that BaseActivity is not being logged in the Logcat.

```
  public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

    BaseActivity context;
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr; //TO CALL OUT THE CLASS OF THE ALARM SERVICE
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent; // FOR TARGET FUNCTION TO PERFORM WITH BROADCASTRECEIVER

    BaseActivity(){
        context=this;
    }


    @Override
     protected void onStart(){

         Log.i("RootActivity:SampleBootReceiver", "On Timeout after 1 min");

         super.onStart();// CALLING ON SUPER CLASS METHOD OF ALARM MGR

   if(alarmMgr != null){    
          alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
             // IN START CONDITION, VAL OF ALARM IS NOT NULL, WILL ABORT INTENT, ELSE WILL

   START()

         }

 }

 // CLASS IS CALLED WHEN APP IS NO LONGER VISIBLE TO USER (FUNCTIONING IN THE BACKGROUND)

  @Override

   protected void onStop(){

    super.onStop();

    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent= new Intent(context, SampleBootReceiver.class); 

    alarmIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0); 

    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000, alarmIntent);
        //SCHEDULE ALARM TO 1 MIN
    }
    public class SampleBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        // ONCE THE ALARM IS LAUNCHED, WILL LOGOUT THE APP
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
            //LOGOUT OF THE SERVICE
            Log.i("RootActivity:SampleBootReceiver", "On Timeout after 1 min");
            Intent intent_login= new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            //CLOSE ALL OTHER ACTIVITIES AND BRING THE ACTIVITY BEING LAUNCHED TO THE TOP
            intent_login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent_login);
            //stopServiceAndLogout();
            finish();
        }
    }
    public void cancelAlarm(Context context){
        //UPON REACTIVATION OF APP, CANCEL THE ALARM(IF SET) TO ENSURE LOGOUT WILL NOT BE EXECUTED
        if(alarmMgr!=null){
            alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide the stackTrace so that it is easy to answer.

Comment: what do you mean by stackTrace? and where do i employ it to?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `registerReceiver` - you can find some info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter))

You should call something like this inside your OnStart() method:

```
context.registerReceiver(alarmMgr, alarmIntent);
```

**EDIT** - I would do something like this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    BaseActivity context;
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr; //TO CALL OUT THE CLASS OF THE ALARM SERVICE
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent; // FOR TARGET FUNCTION TO PERFORM WITH BROADCASTRECEIVER
    private BroadcastReceiver br;

    BaseActivity(){
        context=this;
    }    

    @Override
     protected void onStart(){

         Log.i("RootActivity:SampleBootReceiver", "On Timeout after 1 min");    
         super.onStart();// CALLING ON SUPER CLASS METHOD OF ALARM MGR    
         setupAlarm(); // this could be called in onCreate() instead    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
         super.onStop();
         alarmMgr.set( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + SIXTY_SECONDS, alarmIntent );
    }

    private void setupAlarm() {
          br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
                        // DO YOUR LOGOUT LOGIC HERE
                        Toast.makeText(c, "You are now logged out.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            };
          registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.myapp.logout") );
          alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.myapp.logout"),0);
          alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
    }
}
```

And make sure you clean everything up in the destroy method:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
       alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
       unregisterReceiver(br);
       super.onDestroy();
}
```

Setting up the AlarmManager and the broadcasting is handled in the setupAlarm() method. In the OnStop() method, you actually set the alarm to go off after 60 seconds (60 * 1000 milliseconds), at which point it broadcasts to the br (BroadcastReceiver) and you can run your logout logic.

**EDIT 2** - I have tested out this code on a Galaxy S5 and it worked nicely. You can find the code [here](https://github.com/BMcFerrin/AndroidExamples/tree/master/InactiveLogoutTest). All you have to do is run the app, press home and wait for 10 seconds and a toast will appear saying you have been logged out.

Comment: But what would you input into the following field when you are needed to create a method for registerReceiver??      private void registerReceiver(AlarmManager alarmMgr,
    PendingIntent alarmIntent) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
  }

Comment: correct me if I were to be wrong, registerReceiver is to broadcast my intent from broadcast receiver, which calls from the target of onStop() and what is the main difference between:  registerReceiver (BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) & registerReceiver (BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter, String broadcastPermission, Handler scheduler), they both seem to have the functionality. thanks

Comment: The main difference between the two is that the registerReceiver (BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter, String broadcastPermission, Handler scheduler) allows for more control -- who can send intents to your receiver and what thread is it running in.
As an aside, could you describe why you are using the AlarmManager for this use case?

Comment: I use AlarmManager to auto perform an user logout when the app is running at the background for (X mins), hence i employ alarmMgr to do a count and when alarm = null, it will do a logout

Comment: what are the am, br and pi variables?

Comment: Sorry about that -- I have edited the post. am = alarmMgr, br = BroadcastReceiver, and pi = alarmIntent (PendingIntent).

Comment: I have used that but I am still logged in as user

Comment: It might be something with your logout logic. If you can post any of the code for `stopServiceAndLogout()` then that would be helpful.

Comment: what do you mean? as in substitute my original logout method, with just a stopServiceAndLogout()??

Comment: I mean the code I linked you to works for me, assuming that your logout code works. I'm not sure what you're logout code is doing, so I couldn't tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare time period  for logout in your Activity.java or in your fragment.java file.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish(); // To CLOSE YOUR APP IN ACTIVITY

               ///LOG OUT CODE HERE


            }
        }, 1800000 ); //HAlf hour -1800000


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is AlarmManager is not able to find the broadcastreceiver to invoke.

Solution to write SampleBootReceiver in different file and declare it in manifest. PendingIntent.getBroadcast will not find it unless it is declare in manifest. Declare it as below (Change packagename accordingly),

```
<receiver android:name="com.app.packagename.SampleBootReceiver"></receiver>
```

Create PendingBroadcast as below (add PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT as last param):

```
Intent intent= new Intent(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
PendingIntent alarmIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (1 * 60 * 1000), alarmIntent);
```

Comment: Try using AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP as mentioned in sample code above. This sample works for me.

Comment: so when you said that the sample works, does it mean that the app logs the user our after 1 min if inactivity?

Comment: It means the BroadcastReceiver (SampleBootReceiver) is triggered. I think main issue here is about invoking Broadcast receiver after one minute. Once that is invoked, we can add any logic in onReceive. First Check if your broadcast receiver is getting triggered or not. After 1 minute you should get logs from onReceive method. Once it is done half battle is won. Then you can add logic for login/logout etc.

Comment: Done a debug earlier and noBroadcast Receiver is not triggered, i don't see and logs

Comment: No clues :( . I have declared broadcast receiver in manifest. Created pending intent and alarm as mentioned above and it works for me. Broadcast receiver is triggered after 1 minute.

Comment: Have been wrecking my brain to find out why, but there seem to have no solution, I have updated the manifest as advised, still no log..could it be an Android thing?